# How to specify test classpath in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have an Eclipse project with the following directory structure:

```
MyProj
    >> src/main/java
    >> src/main/config
    >> src/test/java
    >> src/test/config
```

Inside `src/test/config` I have a properties file called `app.properties` full of properties that both the classes in `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` use.

All the code that I am using to look for the properties file looks like this:

```
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.load(new FileInputStream("app.properties"));

    someString = props.getProperty("app.title.color");
    // etc.
} catch(Exception exc) {
    // Handle exception...
}
```

However when I run this I am getting the following error (handled inside the `catch` clause above):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   app.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

But when I move the `app.properties` file to my project root (at the same level as, say, `src/main/java`) and re-run the code, it works great.

Obviously, this is a classpath issue. If I go to `Build Path >> Configure Build Path >> Source` I see that `src/test/config` is in fact a source folder on the *build path*. Which may not mean its also on the *class path*!!!

**How can I configure Eclipse to look for `src/test/config` on the class path so that I can place my properties file in there but still have it available at runtime (when I run unit tests)?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this (which will ensure your code continues to work should it ever be put into a JAR), is to add `src/test/config` to the classpath of your project, and to load the resources using `getResourceAsStream()` method of `ClassLoader`. e.g.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties")
```

Comment: dty - I was just about to ask "What if I put it in a JAR?" to DNA's response - you stole the words right out of my head! Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, this is a better way. I have used a variant of this many times for loading resources relative to a class, but didn't know about the getContextClassLoader() detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly a classpath issue (because you aren't loading a class here!) - the problem is that your code is loading the file relative to the current working directory, which is your project root by default. FileInputStream has no idea what the classpath is - it just loads files!

You could specify the path to the file:

```
props.load(new FileInputStream("src/test/config/app.properties"));
```

though it would be better to specify the config directory as a system property on the command line (or Eclipse run profile):

```
-Dconfig.dir="src/test/config/"
```

and then load files relative to this directory, something like:

```
public static final String CONFIG_DIR = System.getProperty("config.dir");
props.load(new FileInputStream(CONFIG_DIR+"app.properties"));
```

Comment: Thanks DNA and thats a great suggestion - I was about to ask you a followup question but dty answered it before I could ask. Thanks again (I upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 0):

The folders are merged, but you have to access the properties file differently, as resource relative to the class:

```
    InputStream is = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/app.properties");
```

Note the leading "/".